# Persisting Pointer to Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, memory-address

**Problem: Need Unique Identifier**

I'm saving a custom object using NSArchiver. It retains all of my objects data, however, everytime I archive and unarchive it gives them new addresses

```
"<Item: 0x17005d070>",
"<Item: 0x17005e4b0>",
"<Item: 0x17005e4e0>"

"<Item: 0x170059fe0>",
"<Item: 0x170059ec0>",
"<Item: 0x17005a0a0>"
```

For the same 3 objects.

This causes problems because I need to hold a copy of some of the items and persist this copy, and later compare the copy to the original for equality `[currentItem isEqual:oldItem];` Even when this should return true (i.e. the object is the same in terms of name, location, etc.) it will return false because the pointers are different. What's the solution to this? I've thought about adding a uniqueID to each object and then just storing that uniqueID, but that seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do.

**Solution:**

You can't rely on an objects memory address as a unique identifier. Use [NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not implemented `isEqual:` for your Item class. Implement it. Otherwise, as you've observed, we fall back on NSObject's definition of `isEqual:`, which is identicality (i.e. these are one and the same object). It is up to *you* to tell Cocoa that an Item should return true if the object is the same in terms of name, location, etc.; it doesn't magically know this.

Comment: I see. I think I'll have to add a unique identifier then, since my objects can be identical in every respect other than their addresses in memory, which I dumbly thought were persistent. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, that's exactly what a unique identifier is for! And luckily this is now very easy to do in Cocoa Touch. You shouldn't rely on memory address for anything in any case (except when debugging).

Comment: @rmatt oh really? Is there a particular resource you could point me towards?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html